# How can I delete my account?

Tags: support

I want to delete my account, but can't find an option to do so.

What is the procedure for this?

Comment: I have to ask: why?

Comment: Same here! I'm saddened! Would you consider just letting your account lie dormant, instead?

Comment: Im considering deleting my EL&U account, too.

Comment: Great answer, my last action before deletion will be upvoting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to delete your account:
>
> 1. **Edit your profile to say "please delete me"** so we can confirm your
>      ownership of the account.
> 2. **Obtain your user page URL or numeric user ID**. This is linked from
>      the top of every page of the site,
>      when you are logged in.
> 3. **Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page** on
>      the site. Where it says "contact us",
>      click that. In your email, you
>      **MUST** include your user page URL or user ID so we can find your account.

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979)